# I want to merge two csv files in aws lambda which are placed in s3 , i have written code in python but want to perform same thing over AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    reader = csv.reader(open("s3://sme-starsd-ghub-dropoff/ghub_spark/gsap_output/header_file.csv"))
    reader1 = csv.reader(open("s3://sme-starsd-ghub-dropoff/ghub_spark/gsap_output/Data_file.csv"))
    f= open("s3://sme-starsd-ghub-dropoff/ghub_spark/gsap_output/gkgk_combined.csv", "w")
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in reader:
       writer.writerow(row)
    for row in reader1:
       writer.writerow(row)
    f.close()

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': csv.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Comment: reader = csv.reader(open("s3://sme-starsd-ghub-dropoff/ghub_spark/gsap_output/header_file.csv"))
    reader1 = csv.reader(open("s3://sme-starsd-ghub-dropoff/ghub_spark/gsap_output/Data_file.csv"))
    f= open("s3://sme-starsd-ghub-dropoff/ghub_spark/gsap_output/gkgk_combined.csv", "w")
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in reader:
       writer.writerow(row)
    for row in reader1:
       writer.writerow(row)
    f.close()



this code i want to write on aws console to perform same operation

Comment: Please redact the S3 bucket name